# Submitting iOS app with password protected content

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

Is it possible to submit an iOS app to the App Store, where the content requires login/password and the publisher keeps control over who can have the account? It's somewhat like an Enterprise Distribution, except we don't want to be limited to the employes of the company. This way we could also give access to the content to selected clients.

---

Can't comment yet, so I'll clarify here. 
I know about the reviewer account thing and I've used that before. My question is about restricting acces to the application to the general public but not only to company's employees (as in Enterprise Dist.). Also there's no plan on selling the access thus we shouldn't fall under In App Purchase restrictions.

---

@markhunte: Yes, like FB, except the content is not necessarily online, it may as well be all in the app bundle, and the user registration is at the company's discretion.

Comment: Do you mean like how Facebook does. The content is not in the app but on your servers and you have to sign up in the iOS app to use it as a gate way. Or another example is citrix.

Answer (score 2):

In iTunes Connect, you can provide a username and password for Apple to use to test your application:

> The user name and password for a full-access account for your app. This account is used during the review process and must not expire. Include details for additional accounts in the Notes field.

[image: User name and Password]

However, if your intentions are to not let Apple have access to this content your app will be rejected, plain and simple.